# remove polyline from google map between two points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polyline

I have two arrays of locations. and i want to display two different polylines on single map.

but when i tried for that there is one polyline between last location of first array to first location of second array.

So, i get two different polylines connected by one unwanted polyline.

so i want to remove that polyline.

help me.

```
if(index==0) // first location of second array
                        {
                            if(testarray != null){
                            alert('hityhd');
                alert(testarray);
                            testarray.push(newLatlng);
                            if( testarray[0].line ) {
                                map.removeOverlay( testarray[0].line );
                                testarray[0].line = null;
                             }
                            }
                        }
```